# Is the matrix positive definite given the Gauss-Seidel method converges?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I know that the Gauss-Seidel method converges given that the matrix you want to solve is positive definite. However, I'm wondering if the "converse" of the statement is true. Namely, if $A$ is an invertible symmetric matrix with positive diagonals and the Gauss-Seidel method converges for all initial guess $x_0$, is $A$ guaranteed to be positive definite?

Comment: The answer is no, take a look at the [wikipedia page under convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method#Convergence)